# DbSet<>.Add causes SaveChanges to be called. Why?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm doing a standard function like this:

```
var dbCxt = new dbContext();
var entity = new entity();
entity.Property = "123";
dbCxt.EntitySet.Add(entity); <== SaveChanges is called!!!!

//Do some child stuff.

dbCxt.SaveChanges();
```

I was surprised when I overrode SaveChangs in the DbContext and put a break point that it was being called on the Add to the DbSet. Why is it calling it on Add? It should only ever call it on SaveChanges like ObjectContext does!

How do I prevent this madness? (so much for doing anything transactional!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out why it's doing this. It's a code first migration post with nothing in the change tracker so nothing actually happens from the EF perspective other than doing migration work. It only occurs on the first time you do anything to the DbContext.